has the default value for bytes-per-inode changed
I was surprised to run out of inodes on a filesystem that was formatted relatively recently. When I compared it to another filesystem that was formatted on an older version of Debian (unfortunately I don't know the precise versions used), the older filesystem had over twice as many inodes despite being only two thirds the size.
Filesystem        Inodes     IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      274661376 274661376         0  100% /18tb
/dev/sdb1      732430336 127388618 605041718   18% /12tb

I don't recall manualy specifying inode density for either filesystem, did something change in the defaults? is there some magic size boundary which triggers a different policy?

If your mountpoints accurately reflect the volume sizes, you have indeed crossed a size boundary. mke2fs applies different settings based on the file system size:

less than 3 megabytes: type “floppy”, with an inode ratio of 8192 (bytes per inode) and 1024-byte blocks
between 3 and 512 megabytes: type “small”, with an inode ratio of 4096 and 1024-byte blocks
between 512 megabytes and 4 terabytes: type “default”, with an inode ratio of 16384 and 4096-byte blocks
between 4 and 16 terabytes, type “big” with an inode ratio of 32768
16 terabytes or more, type “huge” with an inode ratio of 65536

See man mke2fs and /etc/mke2fs.conf for details. I suspect the units above should be IEC units rather than ISO, but the man page uses the latter.
“Big” and “huge” file system types were introduced in v1.42, released in November 2011 and available in Debian 7 (May 2013). Large file systems created with earlier versions of e2fsprogs would use the default inode ratio of 16384 bytes per inode, which would explain the inode allocation on your /dev/sdb1 volume.

Interestingly, this seems to cover half my problem the "new" drive has a ratio of round 65536 but the "old" drive has a ratio of around 16384, despite being between 4 and 16 terabytes. Perhaps the "big" and "huge" options didn't exist in the version used to format it.

@plugwash apparently these defaults were added some 13 years ago, with the note that "mke2fs will complain if there are file system types which are undefined", so it's possible this was formatted in a system where these defaults were not present yet and so an admin set it themselves.
